# Coefficient of free term in second order linear ODE using Variation of Parameters and Wronskian Determinant

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Let $J(x)$ and $N(x)$ be two linearly independent solutions of the equation

$$x^2y''+xy'+(-1+x^2)y=f(x)$$

It is known that the general solution of the equation is given by the formula

$$y=-J(x)\int N(x) xe^{-x^2} dx +N(x)\int J(x) xe^{-x^2} dx$$

Then

A) $ f(x)=x^2e^{-x^2} $

B) $ f(x)=xe^{-x^2} $

C) $ f(x)=e^{-x^2} $

D) $ f(x)=x^{-1}e^{-x^2} $

E) None of the above

I am not sure how to find the Wronskian Determinant of $J(x)$ and $N(x)$ because from what I think the solution would be in the form of a power series. If $W(x)$ is found then I can substitute in $\frac{f(x)}{W(x)}= xe^{-x^2}$, but I don't think that's how you suppose to do it.

Can you suggest any way to tackle this problem? Thank you.

Comment: Can I use Abel’s identity to find W(x)

Comment: Thank you @Isham

Comment: Oh yeah forgot that we divide f(x) by x^2 haha cheer mate@Isham

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just take the derivatives and insert into the given formula,
\begin{align}
y'(x)&=-J'(x)\int N(x)g(x)dx+N'(x)\int J(x)g(x)dx\\
y''(x)&=(N'J-NJ')g(x)-J''(x)\int N(x)g(x)dx+N''(x)\int J(x)g(x)dx\\
f(x)=x^2y''+xy'+(x^2-1)y&=x^2(N'J-NJ')g(x)
\end{align}
and the Wronskian term $W=N'J-NJ'$ has the derivative
$$
x^2W'=x^2(N''J-NJ'')=-x(N'J-NJ')-(x^2-1)(NJ-NJ)\implies W=\frac{C}{x}
$$
and assuming $W(1)=1$, one has $C=1$.

Comment: Thank you , very clear @Lutzl